# How do I get a colored texture brush to show up in Open GL ES on white background?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I want to draw with a texture brush, in a color of my choice, on a white background using OpenGLES.

I have a bitmap image which I use CG to load and turn into a texture. This bitmap is mostly black, but has a white circle in the center that I want to use as the "brush". In other words, I want the black part to vanish in the final compositing, but the white part to take on the color that I set using glColor.

The best I can get is with the blend parameters (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE) after setting some opaque bright color is a faded color line on a grey (not pure white background). But when I set the background to pure white, the line isn't visible.

At least in the current situation, the black edges of the original texture don't appear. Most other blend combinations I'm trying cause either nothing to show up even on grey, or to see the entire brush including the black edges, which is no good.

Is anyone willing to explain to me how I should set up my texture and/or GL states to make the bright color show through on pure white, without showing the black texture edges at all? This might be a newbie question, but I've tried working through the blend math, and I still just don't understand how the colors are all being factored together.

Here's the image I'm using as the brush:

[alt text http://www.coldcoffeeandjuice.com/OpaqueBrush.png](http://www.coldcoffeeandjuice.com/OpaqueBrush.png)

Here's some resulting output, when the background is grey, and the glColor4f is set to (1, 0, 0, 1), eg pure red, and the brush is used on a bunch of consecutive GL_POINTs. Note that what's good about this is that only the white part of the brush image shows the color red-- that's right. The bad parts is that the red which I want to be pure and bright is pale due to being blended with the background (?) and/or the white of the brush (?) so that it washes out entirely if the background is pure white. This uses the blend params as given above (src_alpha, one).

[image]
<sub>(source: [coldcoffeeandjuice.com](http://www.coldcoffeeandjuice.com/palered.png))</sub>

Here's what I want to see, given the pure red color (thanks Paintbrush):

[image]
<sub>(source: [coldcoffeeandjuice.com](http://www.coldcoffeeandjuice.com/brightred.png))</sub>

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some images demonstrating what you expect to see and what you actually see?

Comment: Done. Let me know if I'm missing any critical information here. I'm a good programmer, but a little at sea with graphics math and GL states.

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm looking also for this solution, but I can't get the right result using the sample application "GLPaint". Can you share the part of your code where you setup the OpenGL environment ?

Comment: I'm in the same boat as strange99. I'm completely new to OpenGL, and I'm trying draw on a white background by reverse engineering GLPaint. I've done what you've suggested above, plus I've gone through every combination of glBlendFunc, AND just about every combination I can think of for brush texture (black on white, white on black, white on trans, alias/no alias, etc). The best I've been able to achieve is with a white-on-trans circle, with glBlendFunc as above (GL_ SRC_ ALPHA, GL_ ONE_ MINUS_ SRC_ ALPHA), but this still gives me a dull colour, and the semi-trans outer bits are interpreted as

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so you're trying to "paint" a given colour (in this case "red") on to a background, using a mask for the brush shape.

You need to do the following before you start rendering the "paint":

1. First make sure your brush has an alpha channel that corresponds with its shape - that is the alpha channel should look similar to the brush image you posed.
2. Render with these states set (note space to get around wiki markup):

> ```
> // Make the current material colour track the current color
> glEnable( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL );
>
> // Multiply the texture colour by the material colour.
> glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );
>
> // Alpha blend each "dab" of paint onto background
> glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
> ```

See also:
 http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/gl/colormaterial.html

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glTexEnv.html

Comment: Justicle-- Thank you. This achieves the effect I was looking for-- I hadn't come across mention of using the "material" stuff in the API when looking up the blending. 

Can you explain for me-- since I was unable to either figure out the math myself, or find the answer with online searching--why the original technique as posted in the question behaved the way it did? I would like to understand what was really going on there.

Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you - I wrote a bitmap font renderer last year and found out all this the hard way. I can't really say what went wrong in your original code as I don't know what you were doing.
If you are curious, I would eliminate each step I outlined (in turn) and try to reverse-engineer your bug.

Comment: I guess I should point out that the important "tinting" operation is enabled by the `glTexEnvf` call. Each texel is multiplied by the current colour - so white (1,1,1,1) x color (R,G,B,A) = (R,G,B,A); and black (0,0,0,0) x colour = black (0,0,0,0). The other parts are just enabling the tinting to actually work.

Comment: Thanks Justicle. It's that final bit of tinting info that I was after.  Thanks!

Comment: Hello Justicle,
I've tried to do same thing as an author. Finally I've found  paint example. In this example I changed background color to white by changing clear color in erase method glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

I've changed blending method for texture according your recommendation, but it still raw black square around my brush. Can you please advice me what to check? I'm really noob in OpenGL, sorry if my question is a bit stupid.

Comment: You should write up your steps to repeat and ask a SO question, there's about a million things that can go wrong. Sorry.